# Cannot add to dom an onbject that has an elements as a prototype

Tags: javascript, html, dom, prototyping

Consider this setup:

```
function makeObj(a){
   this.foo = 'bar';
   this.prototype = a;
}

b = makeObj(document.getElementById('foo'));
document.getElementById('bar').appendChild(b);
```

this gives an error:

> Node cannot be inserted at the specified point in the hierarchy"  code: "3

Why so? Object `b` has a valid element as its prototype. Shouldn't it have worked?

Comment: Although the browser provides an interface to the DOM in JavaScript, the DOM *is not* JavaScript.

Answer (score 4):

There are several issues here.

First `makeObj()` isn't making a new object at all.  It's just a function call and `this` in that function call is likely referring to the `window` object.  You would have to use `makeObj()` with the `new` operator to actually create a new javascript object.

Secondly, you can only append DOM objects to the DOM, not regular javascript objects.

Thirdly, just assigning a DOM object to another object's prototype does not make that other object suddenly become a DOM object.  If you want a DOM object, you need to create a DOM object using something like `createElement()` or one of the other documented ways of creating DOM objects.

If you can describe more about what you're really trying to accomplish, we could advise further.

Comment: And even it was called with `new`, `this.prototype = a;` would not make `this` inherit from `a`.